# popular free-to-use api doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, api, heroku

I'm trying to use this api in my pet project, 
 but when I test it on docs page - POST request "create User" 
 it always sends back 401: Unauthorized
The question is: how I can create a new user? 
I think this free-to-use api is very popular:
api link: 
https://nestjs-boilerplate-test.herokuapp.com/docs/#/

Comment: This seems to be problem regarding security token.   When you try out the "one create user" directly without clicking "authorize" button on the upper right corner, you get 401 Error: Unauthorized  error. So you need to create a bearer token before hand and pass it onto to the post request header for it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because you are not authorized to use the api.

You need a TOKEN or an API KEY to be able to make request to that API server.